# Java SocketChannel register() for multiple OP codes is never selected

Tags: java, selector, nio, socketchannel

I've built a Selector-based system in Java that can accept multiple clients. It has a ServerSocketChannel registered under OP_ACCEPT, which accept()s the incoming connection and registers the resulting SocketChannel with the selector again. Here's that bit:

```
ServerSocketChannel insock = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    insock.configureBlocking(false);
    insock.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(6789));

    Selector sel = Selector.open();
    SelectionKey joinchannel = insock.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    System.out.println("Ready to accept incoming connections.");

    while (true) {
        int ready = sel.selectNow();
        if (ready == 0)
            continue;
        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = sel.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
            if(key.isAcceptable()){
                SocketChannel newConnection = insock.accept();
                System.out.println("New client "+newConnection+" connected.");
                newConnection.configureBlocking(false);
                newConnection.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_READ).attach(new DGPlayer());
            }
```

If I register the new SocketChannel for OP_READ, this works fine. The check for isReadable() succeeds, reads data. Here's that bit:

```
else if(key.isReadable()){
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                int trans = ((SocketChannel)key.channel()).read(buf); buf.flip();
                byte[] ba = new byte[buf.remaining()]; buf.get(ba);
                String msg = new String(ba, 0, ba.length, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                if(trans > 0){
                    DGPlayer client = (DGPlayer) key.attachment();
                    System.out.println(client.name+": "+msg.trim());
                }
            }
                //              else if(key.isWritable()){
//                  ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
//                  buf.clear();
//                  buf.put(((String)key.attachment()).getBytes());
//                  buf.flip();
//                  
//                  SocketChannel target = ((SocketChannel)key.channel());
//                  while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
//                      target.write(buf);
//                  }
//                  
//                  key.attach(null);
//              }
```

If I register the SocketChannel for OP_READ|OP_WRITE, however, nothing happens. As far as I can tell, the selector never finds the channel to be either readable() or writable(). The only change is registering the channel for WRITE permission.

Any idea why this might be?

EDIT - For completion's sake, here's some client code:

```
while (true) {
        int readyChannels = sel.select();
        if (readyChannels == 0)
            continue;

        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = sel.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();

            if (key.isReadable()) {
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                int trans = ((SocketChannel)key.channel()).read(buf); buf.flip();
                byte[] ba = new byte[buf.remaining()]; buf.get(ba);
                String msg = new String(ba, 0, ba.length, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                if(msg.trim().length() != 0)
                    System.out.println("Response from server: "+msg.trim());
            }
            else if(key.isWritable() && messages.size() > 0){
                String message = messages.remove();
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
                buf.clear();
                buf.put(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

                buf.flip();

                int written = outsock.write(buf);
                while(buf.hasRemaining()){
                    outsock.write(buf);
                }

                System.out.println("Wrote '"+message+"' to server");
            }
            keyIterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

(The Client registers the Server for OP_READ|OP_WRITE)

Comment: Ah, okay. I'd hoped it was something obvious! I'll post up some code in a sec.

Comment: Even if it is something obvious, it never hurts to post your code when you ask a question.

Comment: Sure thing. I've put up some server code. It's very verbose, i didn't want to clutter the question up with it. I'll put the client code in an addendum or something.

Comment: What is `messages` from your client code? A `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: It's just a LinkedList<String>. This is the latest bit I've implemented, so I don't know whether that's the done thing. For testing purposes, the list already contains something to send. This sends find when registering for OP_READ.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12278/discussion-between-mtrc-and-jeffrey) - Whoa, okay. Had no idea what that button would do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general it's a bad idea to have a channel registered for `OP_WRITE` if you don't have anything to actively write to it. Most channels can be written to most of the time, so every call to `Selector.select` will return without blocking and consume resources. It's better to add the writing flag to [`SelectionKey.interestOps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#interestOps%28int%29) when you're ready to write something to the channel, and remove the flag when you're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm now varying my interestOps as and when needed. I think I've finally grasped Selectors now...

Comment: @mtrc It's even bettter to just *write* when you have something to write, and only use OP_WRITE when you encounter a short write, i.e. register for OP_WRITE to retry the write operation, and deregister it as soon as a retry succeeds. It's slightly more complex to program but it saves latency.